# Some issue with passing data from JavaScript to MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have been having some problem with what looks like a very simple use case of sending data from a View to a Controller. So I will provide as much detail as possible for someone to help out.

I created a very simple MVC application in VS 2013.

Added a Model class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string[] Hobbies { get; set; }
}
```

Added a ActionResult to the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProcessPerson(Person person)
{
    return View("AddEdit");
}
```

The JS part:

```
function person() {
    var name = "Tommy";
    var birthDay = new Date(1921, 0, 11);
    var hobbies = ["Pinball", "Holiday Camp"];

    return {Name: name, Birthday: birthDay, Hobbies: hobbies};
};
```

The AJAX:

```
function SendPerson() {
    var tommy = person();

    var sendTommyRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ProductRules/ProcessPerson",
        data: tommy,
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

This method is called in a button click.

Below is the data in person object in dev tools:

[image]

Every property has a value.

Here's what it comes-into .NET

[image]

The Date is wrong, that's not the problem I can use a string and then do the required conversion in .NET.

The problem is with the Hobbies array!!!

See that's coming in as null eventhough in JS it has elements.

People have suggested

```
JSON.stringify
```

This time it looks worst:

[image]

Here I guess since nothing is coming in the date is defaulting to the least values and the other two are just null.

So, the question is how to get this work?

Can someone please help me out here. I am struggling with this for a whole day.

Comment: Try to build the array using: var hobbies = new array("xy","wz");

Comment: Insert this `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` before your make a ajax call.

Comment: @greenhoorn First, `new Array("xy", "wz")` is functionally identical to `["xy", "wz"]` (though bracket syntax is generally preferred), second, your syntax is incorrect since it should be `Array` not `array`.

Comment: @MichaelL. There is one little difference btw. Sorry for the spelling mistake I did. Of course it's 'Array' not 'array'...

Comment: Try using `JSON.stringify` and also set `contentType: "application/JSON"` in your AJAX request.

Comment: @greenhoorn  Yes, there are a few technical differences (for instance, you can specify an array size with `Array()` and if some fool has redefined the `Array` object, then `[]` will still work correctly), but I don't believe there is any distinction between `new Array("xy", "wz")` and `["xy", "wz"]` in instances where `Array` hasn't been tampered with. (edit: Differences in _result_, that is.  There may be minuscule performance differences.)

Answer (score 3):

Send `tommy` as `data` and not `person`:

```
function SendPerson() {
    var tommy = person();

    var sendTommyRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ProductRules/ProcessPerson",
        data: tommy,
        //    ^^^^^
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Comment: He does, like you see in the picture. It's just wrong in the codeblock.

Answer (score 0):

```
function SendPerson() {
    var tommy = person();

    var sendTommyRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ProductRules/ProcessPerson",
        data: JSON.stringify({'person' : tommy}),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 changes to your code

Convert the `Date` object to a format that can be understood by the server using `.toISOString()`

Include the ajax `traditional: true`option because you are sending an array of values

```
function person() {
    var name = "Tommy";
    var birthDay = new Date(1921, 0, 11).toISOString(); // change this
    var hobbies = ["Pinball", "Holiday Camp"];
    return {Name: name, Birthday: birthDay, Hobbies: hobbies};
};

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action{"ProcessPerson", "ProductRules")', // dont hardcode urls!
    data: tommy,
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true // add this
});
```